# how to launch Bluez on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, bluetooth, services, bluez, aptdaemon

Trying to launch a BT adapter/manager(default installed on Lubu)a little window informs me that it cannot because there's no Bluez launched.

In terminal: `sudo apt install bluez`, it answers:
Bluez is already the new version (5.46-0ubuntu3)
Then invites me to remove a couple of obsolete packages.

So where's Bluez Daemon to launch?

Writing:`systemctl status bluetooth.service ; hcitool dev`

Answer:

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

Command:`lspci -k | grep -A3 -i "wireless\|network\|bluetooth"`
Answer: `04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Quanta Microsystems, Inc AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
    Kernel driver in use: ath5k
    Kernel modules: ath5k
0f:06.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller
oem@oem-Extensa-5220:~$`

Comment: Update your question with output of `systemctl status bluetooth.service` and `hcitool dev`.

Comment: Sorry to bother, NOrbert, but I'm a real newbie; could you give me precise instructions?
you mean I gotta write those linesdirectly  after the cited answer?

Comment: Open terminal in your system, enter the command above (`systemctl status bluetooth.service ; hcitool dev`) to it, hit `<Enter>`, copy the output of command to clipboard, click [*edit* link to edit your question here](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1024332/edit)  and paste command output here.

Comment: So it seems that you do not have bluetooth hardware. Do you have any? Add output of `lspci -k | grep -A3 -i "wireless\|network\|bluetooth"` to the question.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but it seems that you do not have Bluetooth PCI devices. Are you using USB one (connect it and add `lsusb` to the question)?

Comment: NOrbert, sorry, after your answer  I'm realizing  this old Laptop doesn't have any BT. Dunno why I didn't think of this before, probably I assumed it as it has got Wifi. Should I delete the Question or do u think it may be useful to someone else?

Comment: I summarized steps as answer to help other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do determine the status of Bluetooth subsytem you can do the following

1. Install needed `bluez` component:

   ```
   sudo apt install bluez
   ```
2. Check that your hardware has Bluetooth functionality (on PCI and USB),  find adapter's serial:

   ```
   lspci -k | grep -A3 -i "wireless\|network\|bluetooth"
   lsusb | grep -i "bluetooth\|radio"
   hcitool dev
   ```
3. Check that adapter is not blocked by rfkill and then unblock it:

   ```
   sudo rfkill list all
   sudo rfkill unblock all
   ```
4. Check the status of corresponding systemd service:

   ```
   systemctl status bluetooth.service
   ```

And of course you can determine the model of your device (for example, laptop), and check Bluetooth existence here.